# auto run multiple terminal program commands on a swf file then print results using python

Tags: c#, python, linux, flash, ubuntu

I want to make a python file that takes in a swf file name and runs it in the terminal against 3 programs trid(checks if compressed), flasm(decompresses), swfdump(dumps) and print out the logs to a text file.

ex. command in terminal:
trid -v filename.swf

Is it possible to automate terminal commands? if so how would one write a terminal command like the one above in python?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have anything available to include, maybe some code that is causing your problem, and we can try to fix?

Comment: @ScottKaye - I didnt have much, but I was stuck on how to call programs such as trid from the python code and pass in args as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from subprocess import call, check_output

swf_file  = "filename.swf"
dump_file = "dump_swf.txt"

# run TrID on file and get results
result_string = check_output(["trid", "-v", filename])

# parse result_string - is it compressed?
??? YOUR CODE GOES HERE ???

if is_compressed:
    # decompress it
    call(["flasm", "-x", filename])

# decompile it
dump = check_output(["swfdump", "-D", filename])

# save the decompiled result
with open(dump_file, "w") as outf:
    outf.write(dump)
```

Comment: You can use check_call pass the file object to stdout

Comment: Thanks! that got me started, is there a way to pass in grep with a specific arg into swfdump to so dump only prints that line that has the specific arg passed into grep?

Answer (score 0):

For simple opterations, there is always `os.system`. For more flexibility you may look at the `subprocess` module.

```
import os

os.system("trid -v filename.swf")
```